# Produce multiples graphs in R

Tags: loops, ggplot2, plot

My problem is the following : I'd like to produce 151 graphs in R, with GGplot.

I'd like to start my presenting my data:

I have a first dataset called "df" which contains 152 columns.
The first 151 columns corresponds to the Y-variables.
The 152th column corresponds to the x-variable.
While Y there are 151 variables for 151 graphs, the x-variable is identical for the 151 graphs.

Besides, I have a second dataset called "df_2".
This dataset contains two columns: one column named variable, with the variables names from "df" and a second column, with their corresponding "steady state value".

Basically I'd like to have 151 graphs in pdf, which look like the graph below (with associated variables)
[image]

Here is my code to obtain such a graph

```
df_base = df
steady_state_df = df_2

ggplot(df_base, aes(x = df_base[, 152])) +
  geom_line(aes(y = df_base$capital), col = "darkorange") +
    geom_line(aes(y = steady_state_df$steady_state[steady_state_df$variables == "capital"]), col = "skyblue") +
    ggtitle(paste(' Figure 11: ',  "Capital", sep='')) +
    theme_bw() + 
    theme(axis.title.x=element_blank(), axis.title.y=element_blank(), plot.title = element_text(family="Times New Roman", hjust = 0.5, margin = margin(t = 20, r = 20, b = 20, l = 20)), legend.position="none", axis.ticks.length=unit(-0.1, "cm"), axis.text.x = element_text(margin = margin(t = 10, r = 10, b = 10, l = 10)), axis.text.y = element_text(margin = margin(t = 10, r = 10, b = 10, l = 10))) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks= c(0, 20, 40, 60, 80, 100)) +
  scale_x_continuous(sec.axis = dup_axis(labels = NULL)) +
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = dup_axis(labels = NULL)) +
    coord_cartesian(xlim = c(0,100), ylim = c(min(df_base$capital), max(df_base$capital)))
```

Now that I have such a "graph-code-model" I'd like to implement a loop to get 151 of these graphs, indexed on the variables names. Here is what I have done and does not work :

```
for(i in 1:151){

path = paste("~/Desktop/plotting_task/", varnames[i], ".pdf", sep = "")
pdf(file = path,   # The directory you want to save the file in
    width = 5, # The width of the plot in inches
    height = 5)

ggplot(df_base, aes(x = df_base[, 152])) +
  geom_line(aes(y = df_base[, i]), col = "darkorange") + 
  geom_line(aes(y = steady_state_df$steady_state[steady_state_df$variables == varnames[i]), col = "skyblue") +
  ggtitle(paste(' Figure : ', i, varnames[i], sep='')) +
  theme_bw() + 
  theme(axis.title.x=element_blank(), axis.title.y=element_blank(), plot.title = element_text(family="Times New Roman", hjust = 0.5, margin = margin(t = 20, r = 20, b = 20, l = 20)), legend.position="none", axis.ticks.length=unit(-0.1, "cm"), axis.text.x = element_text(margin = margin(t = 10, r = 10, b = 10, l = 10)), axis.text.y = element_text(margin = margin(t = 10, r = 10, b = 10, l = 10))) + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks= c(0, 20, 40, 60, 80, 100)) + 
  scale_x_continuous(sec.axis = dup_axis(labels = NULL)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = dup_axis(labels = NULL)) +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(0,100), ylim = c(min(df_base[, i]), max(df_base[, i]))) 

dev.off()
}
```

Could someone help me ? Infinitely many thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please help us help you, if you would kindly make this a minimal (!) reproducible example. Meaning, most of the lines that you show are not required. More importantly, we can better help you when we run your code - but we don't really want to produce 150 graphs - so a loop of 2-3 should be enough. And make the plot simple. Use an inbuild data set, e.g., make a simple scatter plot from the iris data set.  It does not need to look exactly like the plot you wish. Ideally, you will notice that when trying to reduce a problem to the core, you may come to the solution by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Simply calling `ggplot(df_base, ...) + ...` does not produce a plotted graph. What creates the output is having the result *printed*.

When executing a line in an interactive session, i.e. executing `ggplot(...` or simply `1`, the interpreter implicitly calls `print` on that result. I.e.

```
> 1
## ==> interpreter calls print(1)
[1] 1
> mean(1:4)
## ==> interpreter calls print(mean(1:4))
[1] 2.49
> p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) + geom_point()
> p
## ==> interpreter calls print(p)
```

If inside a loop, the interpret *will not* call print.

So what is the result from `ggplot`? To peek inside, use the `str` function:

```
> str(p)
```

It does not contain the plot. Instead it contains the data to plot and a description of how to plot.
The magic of converting the data and description to an actual plot happens in `print(p)`, or rather, in `ggplot2:::print.ggplot`.

**How do you print the result in a loop?**

Assign the result to a variable, and print it. I.e.:

```
for (i in 1:151) {
  pdf(...)
  p <- ggplot(...) + ...
  print(p)
  dev.off()
}
```

*Edit:*
If you place the calls to `pdf` and `dev.off` *outside* of the loop, all the plots are written to a single pdf-file with multiple pages.